# drawImage() not working - HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage

I'm trying to create an undo and redo feature for my drawing app. I've checked the execution of functions with console.log. 
On clicking the undo/redo buttons, the functions do get executed, but the drawImage function does not draw the relevant images (older canvas state, newer canvas state, like that).

I'm not sure where I went wrong.

```
//Calls this function every time a piece is drawn - mouseup event
function cPush() {
    cStep += 1;
    var length = cPushArray.length;
    if (cStep < cPushArray.length) { 
        cPushArray.length = cStep; 
    }
  cPushArray.push(document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png"));
}

//Undo 
function undoClick() {
    if (cStep > 0) {
        cStep -= 1;
        var canvasPic = new Image();
        canvasPic.onload = function () { 
            ctx.drawImage(canvasPic, 0, 0); 
        };
        canvasPic.src = cPushArray[cStep];
    }
}

#Redo
function redoClick() {
    if (cStep < cPushArray.length - 1) {
        cStep += 1;
        var canvasPic = new Image();
        canvasPic.onload = function () { 
            ctx.drawImage(canvasPic, 0, 0); 
        };
        canvasPic.src = cPushArray[cStep];
     }
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note. If you convert the dataURL to a Uint8Array you will more than double the number of undos you can fit in the same amount of memory. Base64 strings in javascript store 24bits of information for every 64bits of memory used

Comment: Thanks for the tip! :)